# IndexWorker database connection issue

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I have a working Sitecore local site that I needed to move to a new drive.

The site comes up fine, I can log in, and it works great. I'm having trouble with the IndexWorker service.

The connection string is set up like the others, accessing a local SQL Server DB. I can use the username and password in the connection string connect to the DB and view data/tables with the credentials.

When I try starting the IndexWorker service, I see this error in my log:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
```

My research says this is because the connection string is wrong, but the connection was find on the old drive. Maybe this is permissions related?

Has anyone else been through moving the services to a new drive?

Is there a way to reinstall the services without installing a whole new Sitecore instance?

Comment: The IndexWorker code is located inside the Xconnect search/indexing role. If you’re on XP0 then it’s all on the same role. Within the role you will find the directory App_Data/jobs/continuous/indexworker, this is where the service runs. The connection string data is somewhere within this role (I’m not at a machine to verify). You could find this location by viewing the properties of the service and see which file it is configured to execute.

Comment: Also- it’s important to rule out network viability- you mention that you can connect with the same connection string via SMSS so I assume you’re not running Sitecore in a virtualized environment/containerized, correct?

Comment: I've had this happen to me before.  A few things to Check

1. Make sure the IndexWorker service is running in context of a user who has permissions to the database.

2. Same goes for the AppPool user.  Make sure that user has permissions to the database as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore recommended using SIF to reinstall the services and changing their configs to use the correct DBs. Rather than fighting against moving the services I just did that, and got it working again.